# Crystal-lang file/image upload http server

Tags: http, file-upload, crystal-lang, kemal

Is it possible to have a crystal based web server which handles file upload? I have been looking in the docs, and in many of the crystal web frameworks. I have not found any reference to a simple file upload feature anywhere.

Is this possible, or do I have to look elsewhere to handle my image-uploads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER: As of November 2016 you can use Kemal v0.16.1 and Crystal 0.19.4 for File uploads.

Here's how you can use it

```
post "/upload" do |env|
  parse_multipart(env) do |f|
    image1 = f.data if f.field == "image1"
    image2 = f.data if f.field == "image2"
    puts f.meta
    puts f.headers
    "Upload complete"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for multipart/form-data (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867) in crystal right now. It is something that should arrive in the std IMO.

But right now, Serdar Dogruyol seems to have invested some of his time around that:

- https://github.com/sdogruyol/kemal/issues/40
- https://github.com/sdogruyol/multipart

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can upload file in [shivneri framework](https://shivneriforcrystal.com/)

```
class FileController < Controller


  @[Worker("POST")]
  @[Route("/upload")]
  def upload_file
    path_to_save = File.join(Dir.current, "upload/upload.png")
    field = "fort"
    if (file.is_exist(field))
        file.save_to(field, path_to_save)
        return json_result({
            message: "file saved"
        })
    else
        result = {
            message: "file not saved",
        }
        return json_result(result)
    end

  end
end
```

For more info, visit shivneri doc - https://shivneriforcrystal.com/tutorial/file/